# Как исключить один из процессов (instance) из LB pm2 без отключения сервеса?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Дано:
*pm2 start app.js -i 2*

```
0   │ app    │ default     │ 1.0.1   │ cluster │ 21612    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 36.3mb   │ Costar   │ disabled 
1   │ app    │ default     │ 1.0.1   │ cluster │ 17524    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 34.6mb   │ Costar   │ disabled
```

Возмжно ли с помощью кода исключить один из процессов (instance) из LB pm2, так чтобы все запросы уходили только в оставшиеся процессы?

К примеру исключить процесс 0 и перенаправить все запросы на 1.

Но при этом не отключать сам процесс и не останавливать его с помощью *pm2 stop 0* или *pm2 delete 0*.

И не закрывать сам сервер *server.close()*

Comment: Из документации следует, что нельзя. Для чего вам это нужно и что вас останавливает от остановки процесса по id? Это как раз подходящее решение.

Comment: @mimoprohodil при большой нагрузке остановка процесса, даже с использованием --kill-timeout приводит к потере запросов

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [`pm2 scale`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#cheatsheet) чтобы масштабировать по вертикали количество процессов во время выполнения. Обратите внимание, что он работает только с режим кластера. Пример:

- `pm2 scale APPNAME +2` добавит два процесса.
- `pm2 scale APPNAME -1` уберет один процесс.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667695/4496422</sub>